# how to fetch data from table based on column value and group by its name

Tags: mysql

The below is the table and data.

```
id name  visible image
1  test   1       log.jpg
2  test   2       log2.jpg
3  page1  2       page.jpg
```

How to fetch data from table based on column value(visible) and group by its name i.e., 
from the table i need the name(group by) and with visible =1, if name did not has visible=1 then need to fetch data with visible =2

I need rows like below, need to fetch data in single query.

```
id name  visible image
1  test   1       log.jpg
3  page1  2       page.jpg
```

Comment: You need to better explain your requirements, I don't understand what you're looking for. Also, this is a GIMME TEH CODEZ question and I'm gonna flag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.* 
from your_table t
inner join 
(
  select name, min(visible) as minv
  from your_table
  group by name
) x on x.name = t.name and x.minv = t.visible
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the name of all entries where the visible value is 1? That'd be this, I believe:

SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE visible='1'